# how to modifiy specific attribute in ngrx store?

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

I have a reducer like that:

```
  export interface IVisitState {
      visits?: IVisit;
      redirects?: IVisitRedirect;
   }
  const initialState: IVisitState = {};
  const reducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(fromActions.getVisitsListSuccess, (state, { payload }) => ({
    ...state,
    visits: payload,
  })),
  on(fromActions.getVisitRedirectsListSuccess, (state, { payload }) => ({
    ...state,
    redirects: payload,
  })),
);
```

the interface of the visits look like :

```
export interface IVisit {
  id: string;
  createdAt: string;
  lastUpdatedAt: string;
  guest: boolean;
}
```

From the backend I am getting a date value on createdAt and lastUpdatedAt, but before displaying them on the component I have reformat them using `reformatDateField(dateValue: string)`.

My question is that, how can I call `reformatDateField` fucntion on reducer, so that I do not have to use this function on several component?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question:

```
  on(fromActions.getVisitsListSuccess, (state, { payload }) => ({
    ...state,
    visits: {
       ...payload,
       createdAdd(dateValue: string),
       updatedAdd(dateValue: string),
    },
  })),
```

Better answer:

Ideally, this isn't done in reducers, but in selectors.
You can reuse selectors in multiple components so you also avoid duplication.

Side note, if updating items using the spread syntax is hard - take a look at [ngrx-immer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngrx-immer)